# R: Date format conversion

Tags: r, date

I have Twitter data with the following date format:

```
date <- "Wed Jan 07 20:57:02 +0000 2015"
```

Does anyone know if this is a standard date format? And any package that might be able to convert it to m-d-y?

Comment: `?strptime` will help you to convert. looks like "dayofweek month day timein24hformat timezone year"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In base R, you can use `format` and `strptime`.  `strptime` converts character representations to POSIXlt, and `format` will convert the resulting POSIXlt class object to a character representation of the desired format.  See [`?strptime`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/strptime) for more details.  There is also a help page for [`DateTimeClasses`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html).

For this case you can use:

```
format(
  strptime(date, format="%a %b %d %T %z %Y"),
  "%m-%d-%Y"
  )
#[1] "01-07-2015"
```

The format is:

```
abbreviated day of the week                 %a
abbreviated month                           %b
day of month as decimal number              %d
hours:minutes:seconds                       %T
signed offset from UTC in hours and minutes %z
year with century                           %Y
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strptime("Jan 07 20:57:02 +0000 2015", format="%b %d %T %z %Y")
```

i cut the weekday since it won't work on my locale.